# Vnet Peering Between Multiple Vnets are present in Different Different Resource Groups through ARM template

Tags: azure, vnet

I am looking for an ARM template to establish Vnet peering between multiple Vnets (more than 10 Vnets) present in Different Resource Groups.

Could someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to peer with existing VNets, you could refer to [this template](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-existing-vnet-to-vnet-peering/) with two existing VNets in the same or different resource group. If you have more than 10 VNets, you may deploy the template more times. The main idea is to define the existing VNet resources as parameters section of your template, then refer to the [VNet peering template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2018-11-01/virtualnetworks/virtualnetworkpeerings) and add the JSON content to the resources section of your template.

For more references, you could [understand the structure and syntax of Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates) and [VNet peering Requirements and constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-peering#requirements-and-constraints).